# Browser Time different from MySQL Time

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, momentjs, moment-timezone

I'm currently working on a NodeJS-MySQL project, I'm making a controller for a table (graduates). This table has two attributes (created_at, updated_at) that receive the current date and time. The problem is: when I GET the values from this table in the Browser/Insomnia, the date is in the UTC 0 time zone (not what I want), but when i check directly on MySQL, it is in the UTC -3 (my time zone/what i want). In order to get the date values i'm using moment.js and moment-timezone.js.
Some parts of my code:

```
var moment = require('moment');
var moment = require('moment-timezone');
moment().tz("America/Sao_Paulo").format();
```

setting up moment.js (setting the timezone to Sao_Paulo didn't change anything, probably i'm using it wrong)

```
        const result = await mysql.execute("SELECT * FROM graduates;")
        const response = {
            length: result.length,
            graduates: result.map(graduate => {
                return {
                    id: graduate.id,
                    nomeGrad: graduate.nomeGrad,
                    description: graduate.description,
                    created_at: graduate.created_at,
                    updated_at: graduate.updated_at
                }
            })
        }
```

Get for the table graduates (on MySQL, when I use "SELECT * FROM graduates", I get the same values, the only difference being the time)

```
    var dateTime = moment().tz("America/Sao_Paulo").format();
    try {
        const query = 'INSERT INTO graduates (id, nomeGrad, description, created_at, updated_at) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)';
        const result = await mysql.execute(query, [
            req.body.id,
            req.body.nomeGrad,
            req.body.description,
            created_at = dateTime,
            updated_at = dateTime
        ]);
```

And this is how I Post the graduates. Now for the outputs:

```
    {
      "id": "43",
      "nomeGrad": "iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii",
      "description": "ssssssssssssssssssssssssss",
      "created_at": "2021-10-26T23:44:10.000Z",
      "updated_at": "2021-10-26T23:44:10.000Z"
    }
```

The above output is from Insomnia / Browser (Time is 23:44)

```
# id, nomeGrad, description, created_at, updated_at
'43', 'iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii', 'ssssssssssssssssssssssssss', '2021-10-26 20:44:10', '2021-10-26 20:44:10'
```

The above output is from directly typing "SELECT * FROM graduates" on MySQL (Time is 20:44)

```
Thank you for your time and patience for reading this.
```

Comment: most of the time you will use UTC time because you can easily modify the timestamp client-side to match their timezone.

Comment: @Jhecht I agree with Jhect, for *past* dates (which looks like what you are doing), but not for future dates. Store your data as UNIX time/UTC and only worry about converting it to local time at your presentation layer.

Comment: Do you think I should worry with this? I mean... the database is showing the right time.

Comment: I mean, if it's really that important to you to store it in your timezone, then by all means. Client side you can usually change the timestamp so that people can view it in their timezone. Like I said though, most people will choose to store the data as UTC values so that they can be modified easier later down the line.